# Where to put Testdata?

Tags: c#, testing, resources

I need some images as input for my tests. Where to locate the files and how do I get the path to these files.

Should I use resources? Or put them into the app, or the test app?

I also like to use `nCrunch` later, so it should work even there.

Comment: I'm still lokking for better solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a lot of data for the testing, say up to 1gb.  Having it in SVN is too problematic, so I created a MSI files that deploy the test data into `c:\project_test\...`

Not only that I have unit tests, but also have options inside the production code that are displayed if that directory is found, so some tests could be run even from application.

Comment: That would be possible, but I still prefer to have the testdata relative to my applications. Currently I try to manage the data inside my GIT repo. Maybe I have to consider the decision when the data grows too fast.

Comment: Well, I have video files that needs to be processed, so have no choice :)

Answer (score -1):

You can put the images in an assembly as embedded resources and grab them as part of the test setup. For an example, check out [MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292).

Here's something to ponder, though: If you're writing integration tests that manipulate an image, how are you verifying that the image has been manipulated properly?

Comment: I have some image detection where I try to detect symbols on the image. I can simply check if the function found the symbol on pictures in different resolutions. If you expect a defined result you can only test by hand, save the correct result and use that for further testcases to verify that your method has not changed it's behavior.